# c# Running BackEnd application multiple times synchronously

Tags: c#

Hello I have a back end application in C# that serves data to the front end of a web application.
In the front end UI (programmed with Siemens WinCC Unified) the user is requesting the online data of a production machine for an endless time. The connection to the required machine and reading the data is done in the C# application with special dll's. With one user everything works perfect :)
But if two users would require data from different machines, how should the C# application serve data for the different two users at the same time? The data reading from the required machines is done with high frequency (every 30 ms) and the time is endless, means until the user stops the reading.
So in C# i should be able to connect and read data from several machines at the same time.
How can i manage this? Let's say the data reading is done in a method called "Read_Data". Should i call this "Read_Data" multiple times in different threads? Or should i create dll's, and call this dll's multiple times? Really confused how to manage this :(

Comment: How many clients do you expect to have connected? And are you required to use endless connections (can you change the client to poll data?)?

Comment: Hi  We can limit it with 4-5 clients that will connect at the same time. With endless i mean that the client will stayed connected with unknown time. We can limit this also with 5 or 10 minutes, so if he wants he can extend the time. I mentioned the endless issue therefore: It will not be possible that one process or service provides data for the clients one by one, i think  for each client a seperate process or service should be invoked.

Comment: I’d recommend threads then since your expected number of clients is small.

Comment: Would using threadpool better in this way? Or starting threads when needed?

Comment: Just when needed

Answer (score 0):

Threads.  30ms is a fast update rate (are you sure WCCU will handle that?  What are you doing?  Real-time trace?).  You want to minimize your comms load, which means if more than one user wants data from the same machine, your software should only execute one read action for both users.  This is all easier to do in one application, with threads.

E.g:

- User1 (request M1)
- User2 (request M1)
- User3 (request M2)
- User4 (request M3)
- User5 (request M3)

Application polls machines M1, M2 and M3.  Serves m1 data to User1&2, M2 data to User3 and M3 data to User4&5.

Streams/connections to each machine are established when there are >0 users requesting data of them.  Disestablished when there are ==0 users requesting data.

On a side note, do you have only one WCCU RT instance with multiple users connecting?  If yes, how will you tell which user wants what?

Comment: There is one RT running on a server. WinCC Unifed has a system variable that identifies the user on the client side. So if user1 is sending a request, over a local script the username variable will be attached to the request. In this way the C# Backend application always knows from which user the request is coming. 2) 30 msn works fine because the application is running in a intranet enviroment. With multiple users perhaps we can make it 50 msn. We are collecting the current values of the machines near to realtime. 3) Would it make sense to use threadpool or open single thread as needed?

Comment: 1) okay now I understand.  In this case WinCC Unified requires no license, I presume? ;)
2) okay, good to know for my future reference, thanks!
3) Sorry now you're getting beyond my level of expertise :/ I would open single threads as needed, but I don't know if that's ideal.  Perhaps you could restructure your question based on where we are currently and ask which is more appropriate.